# How to extract ide autocomplete in vue js component

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I'm building a component library for my company and I'm using `vuetify` with `vue.js`.

I need to create custom components like `company-autocomplete` which will use the vuetify `<autocomplete />` component.
The question is: How to make the props suggestions in `IDE` work with `<company-autocomplete />`?

salva-autocomplete:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
</script>

<template>
  <v-autocomplete />
</template>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

app.vue:

```js
<salva-autocomplete #I want the suggestions to appear here />
```

I tried to make the `salva-autocomplete` suggestions to show, but it didn't work.

Comment: I think you can try extending the existing component, or try applying interface in typescript to component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you need to define props for your newly created component, `salva-autocomplete`.

In Vue SFC - Composition API, you can do that by macro defineProps.

I assume, that you also want the developers allow to edit the vuetify autocomplete component, so except your newly created props, I will extend the props of VAutocomplete component. We can do that by creating a type:

```js
import type { VAutocomplete as VuetifyAutocompleteTypes } from 'vuetify/components';

type Props = VuetifyAutocompleteTypes['$props'] & {
  someOtherProp: string;
}
```

as you can see, we are 'merging' type `VuetifyAutocompleteTypes['$props']` and our newly created type with `someOtherProp: string;`

Now, you can use it in `defineProps` macro like below:

`defineProps<Props>();`

As easy as that! So now, if you import this component in other Vue file, the IDE should reccomend you all the props available from `VAutocomplete` element and also your newly created prop, `someOtherProp` of type *string*.

I created a `test` component with this implemented and after importing it in other component, I have right suggestions from IDE:

[image: Passed props example]

[image: My prop example]

There also exist `withDefaults` macro, which you can read about on [Vue Docs](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#default-props-values-when-using-type-declaration). You may use that as well.

Have a nice day.